# Upload XML File in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS. My requirement is to upload the XML file from UI, which will further converted into JSON object. I had tried and google it but not found any proper solution. Please someone help me. thnx

this is my file and button code in html

```
<input type="file" id="importFile" mg-model="aclFile"/>
<input type="button" class="btn green" ng-click="uploadAclFile(aclFile)" value="Import" />
```

And this is angular js function

```
$scope.uploadAclFile = function(xmlData) {
alert("xmlData: " + doc);
}
```

Comment: I just tried to call angularjs function with xml file argument and try to print it into console but it's giving undefined.

Comment: That means nothing. Put some code you've tried in there...

Comment: thnx for response, I have edited my question

Comment: Well you are referencing doc which is not a variable.

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeppee I got it, Here What I did

For file input-

```
<input type="file" id="importFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadXmlFile()"/>
```

JS-

```
$scope.uploadXmlFile = function(){
  var file = document.getElementById('importFile').files[0],
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(e){
      $scope.data = e.target.result;
      alert($scope.data);
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
};
```